# Google MAP not working in Android Browser

Tags: google-maps

```html
 <p id="mapBtn" >
                        Click the button to get your position.
                    </p>
                    <div id="mapholder"></div>
```

```js
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("mapBtn");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    accur = position.coords.accuracy;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon, accur)
    mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
    mapholder.style.height = '250px';
    mapholder.style.width = '500px';

    var myOptions = {
    center:latlon,zoom:14,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
    }
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}

</script>
```

I have added a map in my website, which is working on iphone, windows and some of the android device also, Like samsung s4, but its not working in google phone, asus phone and some of the other android device.

Comment: Wonder if you would post your website

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code on these devices:

```
2.3.5: Alcatel Venture
4.0.4: Kyocera Event
4.4.2: LG Tribute
4.4.2: Galaxy S3
4.4.4: Nexus 5
5.1  : Nexus 7
```

and your code works on all the devices.

One possibility is when user first run your app, they clicked `deny` for accessing location. In that case, you can change the setting in:

```
Menu > Settings > Site Settings > All sites > your.website.com >Location access > Allow
```

Comment: Do you tested on Tablets ?

Comment: Yes I did, Nexus 7 is a tablet

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Location` mode on the Android device must be set to `High Accuracy`. Magically, the map appears!